# DevExpress XtraGrid problem setting value

Tags: c#, devexpress

I wonder if someone can help.

I have a LookupEdit within a Devexpress Xtragrid which is populated from a list of filenames, as well as an empty option, and a "new" option.

If the user selects the "new" option, it goes off to an upload form (which is fine), uploads to the new directory and returns to the form.

The problem is that I want to set the form to the new value, but I can't get it to work.

In the EditValueChanging for the lookupedit, I repopulate the lookup and then use GetKeyValueByDisplayText, but the value returned is null for some reason. Yet I've defined an object for uploadfile with a property of Filename and set both the displaymember and valuemember to Filename.

If anyone can help, as I've exhausted my options.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might appear because the new list hasn't been loaded by the editor yet.  Please try to call the

```
 (gridView.ActiveEditor as LookupEdit).Properties.ForceInitialize();
```

method.  Does this work for you?